# Get multiple matches from text in curly braces

Tags: regex

I have this sample file:

```
authoritative;

subnet x.x.x.x netmask x.x.x.x {
    range x.x.x.x x.x.x.x;
    deny unknown-clients;
    default-lease-time 86400;
    max-lease-time 86400;
    option domain-name "bla";
    option domain-name-servers x.x.x.x;
    option broadcast-address x.x.x.x;
    option subnet-mask x.x.x.x;
    option routers x.x.x.x;

    host host1 {
        hardware ethernet 00:e1:4c:68:00:53;
        fixed-address 1.1.1.1;
    }

    host host2 {
        hardware ethernet 01:e2:4d:69:01:54;
        fixed-address 2.2.2.2;
    }

    host host3 {
        hardware ethernet 02:e3:4e:70:02:55;
        fixed-address 3.3.3.3;
    }

    host host4 {
        hardware ethernet 03:e4:4f:71:03:56;
        fixed-address 4.4.4.4;
    }

    host host5 {
        hardware ethernet 04:e5:5f:72:04:57;
        fixed-address 5.5.5.5;
    }
}
```

Now I'm trying to extract the MAC address and IP address parts from within the host x blocks. When I use this file structure (that includes newLines) it doesn't match at all... this is something I'll address later on. 
But for now I'm having a hard time getting all the matches. 
This is what I have so far: [Link to MyRegex](http://regexr.com/3gi5i)
As you can see there, $1 and $2 contain the last mac / ip address entries. 
But how do I get matches for all the entries in the sample file?
I'm sure I'm missing something essential...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What language/tool?

Comment: As I want to simply understand the mechanism, I'm using this online tool: http://regexr.com/.  In the end I'll try to combine the result with bash scripting tools like grep / awk / sed. But for now I'm trying to understand how to prepare the matches by using regex only - if this is possible

Comment: Thank you, but as I mentioned already I want this pattern to only be matched inside a host block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
host.*?\{\s*hardware ethernet\s+(?:((?:[0-9a-fA-F]{2}:){5}[0-9a-fA-F]{2});\s*fixed-address\s+((?:\d{1,3}.){3}\d{1,3}));\s*\}
```

[Tested here](https://regex101.com/r/motBlq/1).

---

**Explanations**

`\s*\}\s*\}` You were matching one closing brace too many at the end of the pattern.

`[0-255]` translates to any digits between 0 and 2, or 5. Not what you want. It's easier to just use `\d{1,3}` here.

`\sfixed-address` You need `\s*fixed-address` here since you may have several spaces before `fixed-address`.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for the explanations. Exactly what I wanted.

Comment: I do have one more question: Why is this solution not working with the condensed version of the sample file? Please have a look at [this](https://regex101.com/r/cjuygq/1)

Thanks a lot

Comment: You probably should remove the `.*` at the beginning of the regex.

Answer (score 1):

Wow your regex looks overkilled. A simplier would be :

`hardware ethernet ([0-9a-f:]+); fixed-address ([0-9\.]+);`

it matches all the ips and MAC addresses. [RegExr](http://regexr.com/3gi5o)

Comment: You're totally right. But if - for some reason this combo is being written outside the host x code block, it would be matching this, too. That's why I wanted to make sure the matches occur in the host block context only.
Thanks a again!

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly write out parts of the string to make it easier to capture than the one you currently have:

```
(hardware ethernet [\da-f:]+;) (fixed-address [\d\.]+;)
```

This way you have two capturing groups so you can easily get the MAC address and the IP Address individually.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned using `awk` eventually here is a working awk:

```
awk '/^[ \t]*host /{hostblock=1; next} hostblock && /}/{hostblock=0} !hostblock{next}
    {gsub(/;/, "", $NF)} /hardware ethernet/{mac[++i]=$NF} /fixed-address/{ip[++j]=$NF}
END{for (k=1; k<i; k++) print mac[k], ip[k]}' file

00:e1:4c:68:00:53 1.1.1.1
01:e2:4d:69:01:54 2.2.2.2
02:e3:4e:70:02:55 3.3.3.3
03:e4:4f:71:03:56 4.4.4.4
```

Comment: Thanks, and the sed solution would look like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45586363/parse-blocks-in-curly-brackets)

Comment: Sorry but `sed` shouldn't be doing this kind of processing. This is what `awk` is made for i.e. to process text files line by line.